# How can I dragging an Object from a Ext.Toolbar to a Ext.Panel?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha products and Sencha Touch 2.

I have a toolbar docked at the left of the page and a workspace beside it. I want to drag an element from the toolbar to the workspace. How can I achieve that behaviour using Sencha Touch 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem concerns 2 problems:

- Drag and drop functionality. Currently, Sencha Touch 2.0.0 only supports `draggable` config, there's no config like `droppable`
- Drag and drop across components. This is even more complex than the first problem.

Work-arounds in `Ext.util.Draggable` still makes a mess, as far as what I've tried to do.

So the answer is just wait for Sencha Touch 2.0.1 official release and hope those functionalities will be supported.

Comment: I tried playing with draggable config http://pastebin.com/aRanzX8a 
But I found that the Object is being dragged behind the workspace panel. I tried to increase the zIndex of the element but still no use.

Comment: `zIndex` takes effect only when you have more than 1 floating component. I guess that you want to drag an item from Ext.Toolbar and drop it into an Ext.Panel? If yes, that actually changes your DOM structure and cannot be done with current `draggable` config.